# SQL join that happens in the view of Django Rest Framework

Tags: sql, django, join, django-rest-framework, django-views

I just want to know what type of SQL join is happening in the following view. I read about types of SQL joins but I am not able to figure out what is happening here.

```
class WishListItemsView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = WishListItemsCreateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return WishListItems.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

My models:

```
class WishListItems(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    #wishlist = models.ForeignKey(WishList,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wishlistitems')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    wish_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='wishitems')
```

I can see it in Django debug toolbar, but it is authenticated so I cant see the queries.

Comment: Well, looking at your code _no_ joins are happening and Django would be making a new query for each of your foreign keys you access.

Comment: Shouldnt  a join happen when we apply a filter in the view?? I am new to this. On what cases join happens then??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No joins are happening in your code. The following line is the queryset you return:

```
WishListItems.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

This filtering does not need any joins, Django will simply use the SQL WHERE clause to make this filter. Suppose the primary key of the `user` here is 1, then the query would be somewhat like:

```
SELECT <ALL OF YOUR TABLES COLUMNS HERE> FROM "<APP_NAME>_wishlistitems" WHERE "<APP_NAME>_wishlistitems"."owner_id" = 1
```

You can see the exact query by writing:

```
print(WishListItems.objects.filter(owner=user).query)
```

Moving further if you *do* want to make  some join for optimizing or speeding up things use [`select_related` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) which will make Django use an INNER JOIN:

```
WishListItems.objects.filter(owner=user).select_related('owner', 'item') # select the related owner and item
```

Comment: Hello @Abdul can you help me on this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861083/using-select-related-in-django-view-increases-query-times  select_related question