# Using select_related in django view increases query times

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-select-related

I thought of trying to use **select_realted in Django view** to boost the performance. And I compare the results before using select_realted and after using it.

Although I see the reduction of significant number of queries, the time however rises. So I am not sure whether to use select_related in every view or not use them.

I just want to know when to use them and when not to.

My view is :

**Before:**

```
class ProductAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

**After:**

```
class ProductAPIView(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    #queryset = Product.objects.all()

    queryset = Product.objects.select_related('merchant','brand','collection','sub_category')
    pagination_class = CustomPagination
```

My models:

```
class Product(models.Model):        
    merchant = models.ForeignKey(Seller,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=False)
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(Subcategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # is product featured?
```

The images before and after the use of select_related.

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Here we can see that the number of queries are reduced to 124, but the time is increased to 227. So, should i be using select_related? When to use it or when not to use it??

Comment: there is no point in using `select_realted` if you're not using the fetched relations.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 1):

the `select_related` in Django is actually `JOIN` in SQL.
`select_related` will fetch your related fields as well with your object in only one query.
for example imagine if you have a **Book Model** and you have this following code:

```
# Django will execute another query for getting author name
book = Book.objects.get(id=1)  
author = book.author.name
# 2 queries executed
```

In this example you have executed only one query but for getting the `author.name` Django will execute another query. But if you use `select_related` Django will get the author too in just one query.

```
# Django won't execute another query for getting author name
book = Book.objects.select_related('author').get(id=1)  
author = book.author.name
# 1 query executed
```

Note that you don't need to select all of your related objects in `select_related` if you don't need them.
Please check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237042/whats-the-difference-between-select-related-and-prefetch-related-in-django-orm) in stackoverflow to know what's the differences between `select_related` and `prefetch_related` and when to use them.
also check out this [link](https://scoutapm.com/blog/django-and-the-n1-queries-problem) to know more about n + 1 query problems.